# How to load an image with fixed size in tornadofx's ImageView

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

When I'm using JavaFX, Image with the tornadofx, everything works, but it's not async.

```
imageview {
    image = Image(url, 200.0, 200.0, false, true)
}
```

so I'd like to do it the native tornadofx way, but I'd like to resize it as well.

```
imageview(url, 200.0, 200.0, false, true)
```

this constructor doesn't exist, but I can't really resize it, as there's no setHeight and setWidth methods I could use (at least I can't see them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it like this, but I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it.

```
setPrefSize(100.0, 100.0)
imageview(url) {
    fitHeightProperty().bind(parent.prefHeight(100.0).toProperty())
    fitWidthProperty().bind(parent.prefWidth(100.0).toProperty())
}
```